# Editing only filtered entries in an Access form using VBA

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I have been adding on to the Access contact template to create a database which can manage contacts and the main form that opens up has a datasheet filled with all the contact info. I check-box functionality to each item. If this box is checked, you can run certain actions on all the checked box items. I have created a macro that can select/deselect all of contacts at once.

But what I am trying to do is enable it so that when you click the button, it selects only the items that are currently shown. So if I apply a filter in the form for lets say Zip Code, I can hit the button that will change the "Action" field to "Yes" so that I can run the actions on it (bulk send email, export all to outlook, create address labels, delete, etc.).

In Excel this could be done with a .visible type thing, but there doesn't seem to be a function like that for access. I have done all my other methods through creating a `recordset` of the data, but this `recordset` won't have the same filters.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a checkbox, you can either use 0 or -1. -1 for checked and 0 for unchecked in `vba`.

```
Me.checkboxname.Value = -1
```

now what you can do is select all the checkboxes in your form, create a function or a sub for onclick event from the button and add this code that should check all boxes:

```
'code not tested but should work fine
Dim ctrl As Control '//, chbox As CheckBox

For Each ctrl In DAO.Controls 
    If Typeof ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then 
         '// Set chbox = ctrl
           Me.ctrl.value = -1  
        End If 
    End If 
Next ctrl
```

Comment: That is getting an error of Method or Data Member not found within the Controls part of DAO.Controls. Also will this only select the objects that are shown? I want to be able to change the filters and quickly just select all the boxes.  Last question, I have other checkboxes as part of the contact sheet, so I only want to edit the Checkboxes which are under the "Action" field, not the other fields.